# Can I define a method well as give it a value, and assign other methods inside an object literal?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I know I can do this perfectly:

```
var Objeto = {};
Objeto.method = function(){alert("a method of \"Objeto\" ")};
```

Or this way works too:

```
var Objeto={method:
{property:"a property inside a method",
method_property:function(){alert(this.property)}
}
};
Objeto.method.method_property();
```

I can also do this, look what what I have in mind this time related to my question:

```
var Objeto = {};
Objeto.method = function(){alert("this is a method of \"Objeto\"")};
Objeto.method.property = "this is a property of \"Objeto.method()\" ";
Objeto.method.method_property = function(){alert(Objeto.method.property)};
Objeto.method.method_property();
Objeto.method(); // see I define this method how can I do this with a object literal if possible
```

Now how about this, which it is my question:

```
var Objeto = {method:function(){
alert("this does not work")};{method_property:function(){
alert("neither this works")};
```

My intention: Objeto.method(); // alert this does not work with the object literal
The same way I intended: Object.method.method_property();// neither works but in the upper above methods I did the same thing so is it wrong to do so?

I also know, if you need more comprehension to my question if it's not clear yet what I intended:

```
var Objeto(){method:function(){{another_method:function(){alert("now how do give value to the method before this inside the literal of course")}}};

var Objeto = {method:{another_method(){alert("works but /"Objeto.method/" is actually a property not method")}}}
Objeto.method.another_method();
```

The question is quite simple, can I give value to a method and assign a new method inside a Object literal?

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect in places, and the formatting is horrendous for legibility, have another look at your code and reformat if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard approach would be

```
var Objeto = {
  method: function() {
    var f = function(){alert("this is a method of \"Objeto\"")};
    f.method_property = ...;
    return f;
  }()
};
```

};

Comment: I like your answer, it works but rather confusing I say.